# DataGridViewComboBox - How to allow any value?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having some trouble with VisualStudio 2010 C# Winforms.

I have created a DataGridView with an unbound column that is of type DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.  The column works fine, except unlike a normal ComboBox, I can't seem to type in just any value.  I am forced to pick a value from the list.

Is there a property I need to set or another type I can use that will allow me to enter any value in the cell in addition to providing a list to pick a value from?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think there is a property that will allow this, but I found an answer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163669.aspx) that worked with a small modification.

Try adding the following 2 event handlers, here assuming a column named `comboBoxColumn`:

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, 
        DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox c = e.Control as ComboBox;
    if (c != null) c.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
}

private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, 
        DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == comboBoxColumn.Index)
    {
        object eFV = e.FormattedValue;
        if (!comboBoxColumn.Items.Contains(eFV))
        {
            comboBoxColumn.Items.Add(eFV);
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = eFV;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked great for what I needed, with one exception. When i tried to edit a different column, it gave me an error, so I added something to the `EditControlShowing` event in order to detect which column was being edited... (I use VB.NET so forgive me if the syntax is a little different....)  `If dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = comboBoxColumn.Index Then` (and the closing `End If` around everything in that event)

Answer (score 0):

DataGridViewComboBoxColumn is designed rather for select from possible values - not for typing data. If you want to add any data, you should do it programmatically for desired DataGridViewComboBoxCell:

```
((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1[0,0]).Items.AddRange(new string [] {"A","B","C"});
```